# Control marking of a checkbox in datagridview. vbnet 2015

Tags: checkbox, datagridview

Best regard. I'm trying to do a validation before marking a check box in a cell of a datagridview. If a condition is met, the check must be marked, otherwise not.

The event in the grid that I am validating is CellContentClick and the code is this

```
Private Sub dgvDetalle_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvDetalle.CellContentClick

If dgvDetalle.RowCount > 0 Then

   Dim DifMinutes As Double = 0
   DifMinutes = DateDiff("n", CDate(dgvDetal(20, e.RowIndex).Value), Date.Now)
   If DifMinutes > 60 Then
      If dgvDetal.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = True Then
          TotalSP = TotalSP + 1
      Else
          TotalSP = TotalSP - 1
      End If
     else
         'Here should go the code so that the check of the datagridview is not marked
       End If
     End If
 End Sub
```

The language I use is VB.NET from VS 2015

Thank you very much for your help.

The event in the grid that I am validating is CellContentClick but the check of the datagridview is always selected. I have not found the instruction to cancel the event.

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding the following instructions

```
dgvDetal.EndEdit()
dgvDetal.CurrentRow.Cells(23).Value = 0
dgvDetal.RefreshEdit()
```